# Finding the next date of reoccurance

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I have tasks that reoccur and I am building something that will automatically recreate them for me.

I have this enum:

```
  public enum Periods {
      Day = 0, //every day
      Week = 1, //every week...
      BiWeek = 2, //every 2nd week
      Month = 3,
      BiMonth = 4, 
      Year = 5
  };
```

I need to be able to recreate in these intervals.

Therefore, I might have something that reoccurs the 29th of each month. If the 29th does not exist, like in February, then it should jump to the next best thing which is March 1st.

Is there an algorithm to do this, possibly with the DateTime object?

I need ex:

```
DateTime GetNextOccurrence(DateTime initialDate, DateTime lastOccurrence, Periods p)
{
   if(p == Day)
    return lastOccurance.addDays(1);
   else if (p == Month)
   {
      add 1 month to last occurance month then start at day 1 of the month and keep adding days until it gets as close as possible...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So what is wrong with this question :/

Comment: Try to figure out a better explanation of your problem. It is not clear

Comment: [Holy documentation Batman!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods.aspx)  AddDays, AddMonths, ...

Comment: Perhaps the DDay.iCal library can help.

Comment: I can't get where the `initialDate` comes into play?

Comment: initialDate is important because say we want it to try to reoccur on the 29th of every month, but the last occurance was march 1st because of february, so the next one needs to be march 29th.

Comment: Does initial date should take into account only `Day` part?

Comment: Yes in the case of months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hardcode solution but if you'll provide more generic conditions it would be easier to make something better:

```
private static DateTime GetNextOccurrence(DateTime initialDate, 
                                          DateTime lastOccurrence, 
                                          Periods p)
{
    switch (p)
    {
        case Periods.Day: return lastOccurrence.AddDays(1);
        case Periods.Week: return lastOccurrence.AddDays(7);
        case Periods.BiWeek: return lastOccurrence.AddDays(14);
        case Periods.Month:
        case Periods.BiMonth:
          {
              DateTime dt = lastOccurrence.AddMonths(p == Periods.Month ? 1 : 2);
              int maxDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
              int days = Math.Min(initialDate.Day, maxDays);
              return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, days);
          }
        case Periods.Year: return lastOccurrence.AddYears(1);
        default: return lastOccurrence;
    }
}
```

The updated version even more hadcoded but I've updated code to solve `AddMonth` caveat. The only minor difference with what you wanted is that dates don't transfer to the next month but cycling is preserved.

Comment: Not quite, see the caveat about February...

Comment: Yeah, you updated the question after my answer. I have to think about better solution.

Comment: @user2043533 What do you mean "not quite"? You think AddMonths is so broken is will give you dates that don't exist?

Comment: No, but lets say it has to happen the 29th each month, addMonths will bring you to March 1st, but next month is should be March 29th, not April 1st...

Comment: @user2043533 that's why you addMonths to the original date... OK you're right, I see where there is an issue with his answer.

Comment: So I should then get the Timespan of months between last and original and add that + 1?

Comment: I updated the answer. Does it fit your question now?